# Why is one of my htaccess SEO friendly url rewrites working and the other not?

Tags: .htaccess, seo, friendly-url

Im creating SEO friendly URLs via htaccess rewrites.

I have it working correctly for one set of URLs but when Ive created the rules for another set it doesnt work correctly anymore for that set but still works for the original set, it does use the correct page but the actual address in the URL changes too and it doesnt stay on the friendly URL.

This works:

```
RewriteRule ^toys/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+) toysearch.php?category=$1&dinosaur=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^toys/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+) toysearch.php?category=$1 [QSA]
```

the URL stays as /toys/category

But this doesnt work:

```
RewriteRule ^books/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+) bookssearch.php?category=$1&dinosaur=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^books/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+) bookssearch.php?category=$1 [QSA]
```

The URL changes from /books/category

to:

/booksearch.php?category=story-books

Why is the URL changing for this one and not the other one? All I did was to copy the 2 lines and change the words toys for books?

**EDIT**
These are alll my directives:

```
RewriteRule ^books/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+) bookssearch.php?category=$1&dinosaur=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^books/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+) bookssearch.php?category=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^dinosaurs/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+) dinosearch.php?dinosaur=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+) catsearch.php?name=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^toys/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+) toysearch.php?category=$1&dinosaur=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^toys/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+) toysearch.php?category=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^xmas/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+) xmassearch.php?category=$1&dinosaur=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^xmas/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+) xmassearch.php?category=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file? The "redirect" isn't caused by the directives you've posted, so you may have a conflict? _Aside:_ Your regex do not include an end-of-string anchor so are potentially matching too much - is that intentional? (Although if it is _intentional_ then it's potentially creating a duplicate content issue and leaves your site vulnerable to malicious URL spamming.)

Comment: Thanks, Ive edited my q to include the directives, no the end of string anchor isnt intentional, how do I add that? Is it just a training slash after the closing brackets? Im not very familiar with this so could be missing some obvious things. I am leaning towards refining this structure somewhat and just going for a blanket 'items/category/subcategory/string'  structure then I could turn all these directives into just one or 2 lines

Comment: There's nothing in the code you added that would trigger a redirect. (Presumably you have `RewriteEngine On` earlier in the file? But there is nothing else?) So, to confirm, when you request `/books/story-books`, there is an external redirect? Have you confirmed this in the network traffic? What is the HTTP status code of the redirect?

Comment: I dont actually have RewriteEngine on, the only lines which arnt commented out are: '<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /'  How do you mean an external redirect? My site is pasword protected so I cant use a web based HTTP redirect checker to see the status code, is there another way I can check this?

Comment: You simply look into your browsers console. The network tab in there. And you always test using a fresh, anonymous browser instance.

Comment: Thanks, I get HTTP response code 200. Can anyone tell me how I add the end of string character to the REGEX as mentioned above? Do I just add an $ before the closing brakets?

Comment: "I get HTTP response code 200" - So, no redirect?! But the URL is _changing_? That would seem to suggest JavaScript pushState in your client-side code?! (But that doesn't really make sense; does it?) "end-of-string anchor" - You need to add `$` at the end of the regex, **not** "before the closing brackets". You are also missing the `L` flag on all these directives. (These are side issues, they won't affect the _changing_ URL.)

Comment: just to confirm, Im trying to do a rewrite not a redirect. I want to go to the url 'domain.com/searchterm1/searchterm2' in the browser address bar and for this to stay there but the server give me the content from domain.com/searchcontroller.php?term1=searchterm1&term2=searchterm2